# How can I programmatically transliterate Russian to English?

Tags: c#, programming-languages, translation

How can I transliterate a Russian phrase with c# programmatically?  For example: "**Мне на кризис наплевать, вылез в топе гоу бухать**?"

Comment: @Justin the alphabet is Cyrillic, so odds are good it's Russian.

Comment: @Justin - Russian (I think). Reach - Stack Overflow is an English language site, so can you please post in English.

Comment: Whoops, sorry for my edit confusing translate/transliterate.

Comment: Perhaps this link will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841874/how-to-transliterate-cyrillic-to-latin-text

Answer (score 5):

I don't know, use the [Google Translate Javascript API](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2008/03/20/google-releases-language-translation-api/)?

Or maybe the [Transliteration API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/transliterate/overview.html)?

Comment: Translation is NOT the same as transliteration. This answer is wrong wrong wrong.

Comment: They have a REST API too so he could probably formulate a call from within .NET through HTTP

Comment: @Jason - title says translate, post doesn't.
@Reach - can you clarify?

Comment: Right, they have both a translation API and a transliteration API :-)

Comment: @slandau: Someone edited it to say "translate." The original title did not. People who don't know shouldn't be editing titles.

Comment: @Reach: There are plenty of examples here: http://code.google.com/apis/language/transliterate/v1/getting_started.html

Comment: There just javascript, as I need c#

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to come up with a set of transliteration rules (effectively a mapping from Cyrillic character codes to Latin alphabet character codes). Then for a given stream of words encoded in the Cyrillic alphabet, just apply the mapping and produce the resulting stream of words encoded in the Latin alphabet.

Comment: +1. A small note: Since I've had some experience with transliterating my first language (Greek) I must add that this process is not always easy. The reason is that diphthongs in each language may produce totally different sounds than normally expected. So if the poster considers making mapping rules, make sure you prioritize diphthong parsing and then normal letter transliteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
Мне на кризис наплевать, вылез в топе гоу бухать = 
Mne na krizis naplevat', vylez v tope gou bukhat'

Аа = a
Бб = b
Вв = v
Гг = g
Дд = d
Ее = e
Ёё = io
Жж = zh
Зз = z
Ии = i
Йй = y
Кк = k
Лл = l
Мм = m
Нн = n
Оо = o
Пп = p
Рр = r
Сс = s
Тт = t
Уу = u
Фф = f
Хх = kh
Цц = ts
Чч = ch
Шш = sh
Щщ = shch
Ъъ = '
Ыы = y
Ьь = '
Ээ = e
Юю = iu
Яя = ia
```