# Converting Unicode string to ASCII

Tags: powershell, unicode, ascii, special-characters, diacritics

I have strings containing characters which are not found in ASCII; such as á, é, í, ó, ú; and I need a function to convert them into something acceptable such as a, e, i, o, u. This is because I will be creating IIS web sites from those strings (i.e. I will be using them as domain names).

Comment: In general, it's called transliteration. Normalizing to FormD and filtering will work to convert composed Latin letters to [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) letters but not ligatures  (ǆ, ǣ, ĳ, … ) and such. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841874/how-to-transliterate-cyrillic-to-latin-text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function Convert-DiacriticCharacters {
    param(
        [string]$inputString
    )
    [string]$formD = $inputString.Normalize(
            [System.text.NormalizationForm]::FormD
    )
    $stringBuilder = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $formD.Length; $i++){
        $unicodeCategory = [System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($formD[$i])
        $nonSPacingMark = [System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory]::NonSpacingMark
        if($unicodeCategory -ne $nonSPacingMark){
            $stringBuilder.Append($formD[$i]) | out-null
        }
    }
    $stringBuilder.ToString().Normalize([System.text.NormalizationForm]::FormC)
}
```

The resulting function will convert diacritics in the follwoing way:

```
PS C:\> Convert-DiacriticCharacters "Ångström"
Angstrom
PS C:\> Convert-DiacriticCharacters "Ó señor"
O senor
```

Copied from: http://cosmoskey.blogspot.nl/2009/09/powershell-function-convert.html

Comment: It does not replace polish `ł` letter although

Answer (score 2):

Taking [this answer from a C#/.Net question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/249126/478656) it seems to work in PowerShell ported roughly like this:

```
function Remove-Diacritics
{
    Param([string]$Text)


    $chars = $Text.Normalize([System.Text.NormalizationForm]::FormD).GetEnumerator().Where{ 

        [System.Char]::GetUnicodeCategory($_) -ne [System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory]::NonSpacingMark

    }


    (-join $chars).Normalize([System.Text.NormalizationForm]::FormC)

}
```

e.g.

```
PS C:\> Remove-Diacritics 'abcdeéfg'
abcdeefg
```