# Pester test for PowerShell script fails with differing accent characters, how to fix?

Tags: powershell, pester-5

I have a problem. I want to test my PowerShell script by Pester.
This is my function to test:

```
function Remove-Diacritics {
        param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
            [String]$string
        )
        $cleanText = $string -replace "[\p{Mn}]", ""
        return $cleanText
        #$cleanText = ($string.Normalize([Text.NormalizationForm]::FormD)) -creplace "\p{Mn}"
        #return $cleanText
      }
}
```

Pester test:

```
Describe "Remove-Diacritics" {
    BeforeAll {
        Import-Module D:\scripts\test\patching_common.psm1
    }
    Context "When removing diacritics from a string" {
        It "should remove diacritics and return a clean string" {
            $text = "Café"
            $expectedOutput = "Cafe"
            $output = Remove-Diacritics -string $text
            $output | Should -Be $expectedOutput
        }
    }
}
```

As a result I am getting this error:

> Expected: 'Cafe'
> But was:  'CafA©'

But when I run the script with function in PS terminal it returns 'Cafe'

Can it be because of some encoding?

Comment: Aside from the fact that the pester output looks incorrect (see for this [Displaying Unicode in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/1701026)), I don't think you can remove the diacritics tokens by just removing a complete `[\p{Mn}]` character, to remove the diacritics, see: [Converting Unicode string to ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46660695/1701026).